# Firebase: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf')

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to Firebase Cloud and I am following a video from a few years ago but they are using namedspace v8 and I wanted to use modular v9.

Their code goes as followed:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if(user) {
        db
        .collection('users')
        .doc(user?.uid)
        .collection('orders')
        .orderBy('created', 'desc')
        .onSnapshot(snapshot => (
            setOrders(snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
                id: doc.id,
                data: doc.data()
            })))
        ))
    } else {
        setOrders([])
    }

  }, [user])
```

My Code:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const getDocs = async () => {
      try {
        const collRef = await getDocs(
          collection(db, "users", user?.id, "orders")
        );
        const orderedRef = query(collRef, orderBy("created", "desc"));
        const docSnap = onSnapshot(orderedRef, (snapshot) => {
          snapshot.map((doc) => ({
            id: doc.id,
            data: doc.data(),
          }));
          setOrders(docSnap);
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
      }
    };
    getDocs();
  }, [user]);
```

I am trying to get all the orders from a particular user using their `user?.id` and ordered them by `created` in a descending order and display them in my order component but I am getting this error back `Firebase: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'indexOf')`

**NOTE**

I also tried to console.log at every step(at `const collRef` & `const orderedRef`) and I'm not getting anything back.

Answer (score 0):

Your `collRef` is not a `CollectionReference`, but a `QuerySnapshot` as you assign it here:

```
const collRef = await getDocs(
  collection(db, "users", user?.id, "orders")
);
```

You'll want to assign `collRef` like this:

```
const collRef = collection(db, "users", user?.id, "orders");
```